# X509TrustManager implementation of fabric/crashlytics insecure?

Tags: android, google-play, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

Last week I got the infamous "Your app's ssl cert validation is insecure" [[link]](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/6346016) warning for our app.

As we don't use a custom TrustManager, I scanned the app's apk for occurrences of "checkServerTrusted". The only class that came up is related to Fabric/Crashlytics (most probably `io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.PinningTrustManager`).

Does anyone know if there's a problem with Fabric's implementation of TrustManager? Did anyone using Fabric (and no custom implementation of TrustManager) also get this warning?

I didn't find the source code of the SDK, so I couldn't check myself, however if you see similar results, in a next step I'd contact their support.

**Update:**

- I contacted fabric support and posted to [twitter dev forums](https://twittercommunity.com/t/x509trustmanager-implementation-of-android-sdk-insecure/61694).

Comment: I am not aware that their SDK is open source. A `PinningTrustManager` sounds promising, suggesting that it implements certificate pinning. However, it is possible that it has a bug, or it is possible that Google's scanner has a bug and Fabric's `TrustManager` is fine. I'd head to Fabric support.

Comment: I just did contact their support, I will update the question as soon as I hear back from them.

Comment: @FlorianBarth did you get a reply from them as i'm having the same problem.

Comment: @anirudh-sharma I didn't hear back from fabric support yet. In the twitter dev forums, Michael Bonnel from Twitter told me that they'll be investigating the issue.

Comment: @FlorianBarth Thanks for the reply.Guess i'll have to find an alternate.

Comment: @AnirudhSharma We didn't see this behavior when we shipped our Fabric Android app. What parts of Fabric are you using?

Comment: @MikeBonnell strange.I'm only using crashlytics and nothing else.

Comment: @AnirudhSharma Very odd then, you could try reaching out to Google about this, but it seems like something funky is happening with their checks if some apps are passing and others aren't.

Comment: @MikeBonnell.Yup that's correct.

Comment: @FlorianBarth Which tools did you use to scan your app's apk? I ran in this issue, too and is struggling to find what cause it

Comment: @DoanCuong apktool helps with unpacking & indexing your apk. From there it's a "search in path" in your favorite text editor / shell